# How to properly increment a counter in my postgreSQL database?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Let's say i want to implement a "Like/Unlike" system in my app. I need to count each like for sorting purposes later. Can i simply insert the current value + 1 ? I think it's too simple.

What if two user click on the same time ? How to prevent my counter to be disturbed ?

I read i need to implement transactions by a simple decorator `@transaction.atomic` but i am wonder if this can handle my concern.

Transactions are designed to execute a "bloc" of operations triggered by one user, whereas in my case i need be able to handle multiple request at the same time and safely update the counter.

Any advise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use F() expression, eg.

```
content.likes_count = F('likes_count') + 1
content.save()
```

So the operation will be excuted in database not in python.

From the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/).

> Another useful benefit of F() is that having the database - rather
>   than Python - update a field’s value avoids a race condition.
>
> If two Python threads execute the code in the first example above, one
>   thread could retrieve, increment, and save a field’s value after the
>   other has retrieved it from the database. The value that the second
>   thread saves will be based on the original value; the work of the
>   first thread will simply be lost.
>
> If the database is responsible for updating the field, the process is
>   more robust: it will only ever update the field based on the value of
>   the field in the database when the save() or update() is executed,
>   rather than based on its value when the instance was retrieved.

Comment: thanks for the tips. It's look like what i was seeking.